# Missing continuity condition in theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm going through the proof that all partials continuous $\implies$ $f$ is differentiable.  Here's what my book says:

[image]

What I'm wondering about is how we can use the mean value theorem in step $2$.  Doesn't the MVT require $\mathbf f$ (or its components $f_i$) be continuous on $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ for all $k$?  That's not a part of the suppositions for this theorem.  Did the author just forget to add that $\mathbf f$ needs to be continuous on $U$ or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: When $\mathbf x_k$ and $\mathbf x_{k-1}$ are within the "open neighborgood of $\mathbf x\in U$" mentioned in the statement of the theorem, $\mathbf f$ is continuous on the segment $[\mathbf x_{k-1},\mathbf x_k]$ because it is differentiable on a slightly larger open segment $(\mathbf x_{k-1}-\epsilon\mathbf  e_k,\mathbf x_k+\epsilon\mathbf e_k)$.The MVT is then applied to the restriction of $\mathbf  f$ to the segment $[\mathbf x_{k-1},\mathbf x_k]$ on which $\mathbf f$ is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: May I ask which textbook you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean value theorem is applied to the real function

$$t \mapsto f(x+\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}h_ie_i+te_k),$$
which is continuous since it is differentiable, as its derivative is given by the partial derivative of the function $f$ (just apply the definition of derivative).

For your edit, what he is using is the fact that $\Vert h_k \Vert \leq \Vert h \Vert$, and then putting $\Vert h \Vert$ in evidence.